# How to let the user scroll past the last item in a ListView in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a ListVIew in WPF, that gets a lot log messages when the program runs.
It will automatically scroll to the latest item, which is exactly how I want it (was hard enough to find out how to do that, thanks to stackoverflow I did it though).

When the program is done and I'm examining the log (or, the future user of this little program), and would like to scroll downn past the last item, so the last item is comfortably in the middle of my screen.

I can't simply shove in some empty entries, since the program may run again or another program after the first one, adding more stuff to the log. With empty entries, I would just have a big hole in there.

Right now, my ListView wpf part looks like this:

```
        <ListView Margin="5 5 5 5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Background="Transparent"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:LOG.LogList}, Mode=OneWay}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:AutoScrollToLastItemBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The CanContentScroll makes it possible to scroll by physical space, and not logical. Otherwise, the View would always hook to an entry.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like in order to achieve this you'll need to use the list boxes ItemTemplate, and provide two DataTemplates, 1 for a "LogItem" type, and 1 for a "FooterItem" type, whereby the FooterItem's template includes a margin.  And in your code behind that might add items to your item source, always insert just before the "FooterItem" object, instead of appending to the item list.

Not sure if that is helpful, but it is one way I would go about it.